# Fast estimation of lagged covariance

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, data-science, signal-processing

I am working on a bigger function whose main bottleneck is the estimation of lagged covariance. I couldn't find any function, so I had to make my own:

```
def crosscov(signal1, signal2):
    lags = numpy.arange(-signal1.size+1,signal1.size)
    signal1 = copy.deepcopy(pandas.Series(signal1))
    signal2 = copy.deepcopy(pandas.Series(signal2))
    c = numpy.zeros(len(lags))
    counter = -1
    for lag in lags:
        counter = counter + 1
        cov_matrix = numpy.cov(signal1,signal2.shift(lag,fill_value=0), bias=True)
        c[counter] = copy.deepcopy(cov_matrix[0,1])
    return c, lags
```

In its current form about 90% of the main function is taken up from just crosscov. Is there a way to speed this up? A similar code in MATLAB with its built-in xcov function takes about 4 min, while in Python takes 3+ hours.

I have to estimate the lagged covariance between several pairs of vectors, so the optimal would be to input a matrix and get all possible covariance values for all possible lags.

**Edit**:

I found a better solution:

```
def crosscov(signal1, signal2):
       lags = numpy.arange(-signal1.size+1,signal1.size)
       c = numpy.correlate(signal1,signal2,mode = "full") 
       c = c/len(signal1)
       return c, lags
```

But I think I can speed up my code even more if instead of doing it for pair of signals, I vectorize the whole thing.
For example a 12x32 matrix (12 datapoints, 32 signals) should return a 23x1024 matrix(12x2-1,32x32). This is because it uses all possible lags in all possible combination of channels.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: You are using 2 signals of equal length and then shifting and filling with zeros?  You realize you are going to be getting odd covariance numbers when the shifts are large because you are computing the covariance of signal 1 with a largely empty vector?

Comment: Compare your results with MATLAB for some short simple signals. Also, no need to use `copy.deepcopy` function